Shell script array element value not working in json post query
I have a some url array like below, Later I want to do some post method for each array element. somehow array element not working, but when I try direct url value its working.
# Print the uncommon URLs
echo "Uncommon URLs:"
printf "%s\n" "${uncommon_urls[@]}"


IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a array1 <<< "${uncommon_urls[@]}"
getApp=$(curl -X GET -H "$headers" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "$uri")
#echo $getApp
for url in "${array1[@]}"; do
        echo $url
        url=$(echo "$url" | rev | cut -c2- | rev)
        echo $url
        url=$(echo "$url" | tr -d '"')
        echo $url
       #getApp=$(echo "$getApp" | jq '.redirect_uris -= ["https://172.16.19.31:1111/login/callback"]')
       getApp=$(echo "$getApp" | jq '.redirect_uris -= ["'$url'"]')
       getAppnew=$(curl -X PUT -H "$headers" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$getApp" "$uri")
done

echo urslnew
echo $getAppnew

output
Uncommon URLs:
[
  "https://172.xx.xx.31:3610/login/callback",
  "https://172.xx.xx.31:3611/login/callback"
  
]

"https://172.xx.xx.31:3611/login/callback",
"https://172.xx.xx.31:3611/login/callback"
https://172.xx.xx.31:3611/login/callback
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3411    0  1597  100  1814   2321   2636 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4950
"https://172.xx.xx.31:3612/login/callback",
"https://172.xx.xx.31:3612/login/callback"
https://172.xx.xx.31:3612/login/callback
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3411    0  1597  100  1814   3013   3422 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6423

Code which is working is below.If I put url value directly, its working
getApp=$(echo "$getApp" | jq '.redirect_uris -= ["https://172.xx.xx.31:1111/login/callback"]')

If I define manually like this all works fine
uncommon_urls=(
  "https://172.16.19.31:12163/login/callback"
  "https://172.16.19.31:20383/login/callback"
  "https://172.16.19.31:31990/login/callback"
  "https://172.16.19.31:21480/login/callback"
  "https://172.16.19.31:2851/login/callback"
  "https://172.16.19.31:8549/login/callback"
  "https://172.16.19.31:11092/login/callback"
  "https://172.16.19.31:11092/auth/login/callback"
  "https://172.16.19.31:3355/auth/login/callback"
  "https://172.16.19.31:10602/auth/login/callback"
)


It looks like ${uncommon_urls[@]} already contains a JSON encoded array (if there's no comma after the last item), because then you'd be better off using something along the lines of printf "%s\n" "${uncommon_urls[@]}" | jq -r '.[]' or jq -Rsr 'fromjson[]' <<< "${uncommon_urls[@]}"

Yes That is correct @pmf No comma after the last item. So should I use what you wrote and remove line "IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a array1 <<< "${uncommon_urls[@]}""
What is updated code you are suggesting, I can try same.

What sets uncommon_urls? As you already have a JSON array, there seems to be no reason to break the serialization of that array into multiple shell array elements. (Or anything doing so should get rid of the [, ], and commas so that each shell array element is exactly one URL.)

Filter the URLs based on the uncommon ports
(` uncommon_urls=()
for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
port=$(extract_port "$url")
if echo "$uncommon_ports" | grep -q "^$port$"; then
uncommon_urls+=("$url")
fi
done )
Above code sets uncommon_urls.

somehow I messed up array, If I do not use  IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a array1 <<< "${uncommon_urls[@]}"    for loop getting full value of uncommon_urls[@] not individual one.. I tried     printf "%s\n" "${uncommon_urls[@]}" | jq -r '.[]'   as mentioned by @pmf I can see without [, ], But still same issue.
